# Loop function not firing

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to fire a function called NewSquaresInGrid which removes an existing container grid and adds a new container grid containing X amount of divs. The X coming from a prompt.

The old grid container is being removed and a new grid is being added but the contents created via the loop isn't appearing!

Any idea why it's not working?

Code in question:

```
//Function to be called on button click removing existing grid and replacing with a new one
function refreshGrid() {
    newSquares = prompt("How many squares would you like? (Maximum 100)");
    removeGrid()
     let grid = document.createElement('div');
    grid.classList.add('grid');
    container.appendChild(grid);
    NewSquaresInGrid();
}

function removeGrid() {
    container.removeChild(grid); 
}

//Add a new grid 
function NewSquaresInGrid() {
        for (i = 0; i < newSquares; ++i) {
            let i = document.createElement('div');
            i.classList.add('grid-item');
            grid.appendChild(i);
    }
}
```

Full code at: https://jsfiddle.net/ahq6830j/1/

Comment: What do you expect the value of `i` to be in your loop?

Comment: You're creating `i` twice, once for the loop, and once for the `div`. So the loop will stop working...

Comment: I want to create X amount of divs X being what the user submits in the prompt hence I used i as the variable name so it would auto create the correct amount of divs. If I don't do this I'd have to guess how many divs to create? The loop works so not sure what the issue is exactly.

Answer (score 1):

That is because `let grid = document.createElement('div');` creates a new `grid` variable local to the function. So the other functions that try to re-use the `grid` variable will not have access to it.

remove the `let` and use  `grid = document.createElement('div');` to update the already existing global `grid` variable.

---

But you revisit the part where you re-use the `i` variable inside loops.

Comment: Thank-you that makes perfect sense. The old local/global catches me out! What's the issue with the i variable? If I remove the let as suggested the functions all work correctly.

Comment: @SamJefferies For one it is confusing to use the `i` for the loop counter, and for the variable inside the loop that holds the `div`. Variable shadowing is confusing in the sense that you now cannot use the outer `i` in your loop, and someone reading the code needs to track which one is the "active" one.

Comment: Thanks @gabriele, how would I create the correct amount of Div's if I don't use a changeable i value?

Comment: @SamJefferies i am only saying you should use a better (*unique*) name for the `i` variable inside the loop. Something like `for (let i = 0; i < newSquares; ++i) { let element = document.createElement('div'); element.classList.add('grid-item'); grid.appendChild(element); }`

Comment: Thank-you for explaining. I was under the impression that wouldn't work as the loop would loop over the previous let with the same name and I'd only end up with one. But it does seem to work!

Answer (score 1):

variables declared with `let` in javascript is block scoped which basically means that the `grid` variable declared in `refreshGrid()` function is not accessible outside the function. One option is to globally declare the grid variable like this:

```js
let grid;
```

Also you should rename the `i` in the loop counter to something else so that it does not clash with the other `i` variable inside the loop.